# Jenkinsfile default git checkout failing due access_rights

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to configure my Jenkinsfile to run in one which already have access to my git repository via ssh. When the Jenkinsfile in the repo rootpath is executed, the jenkins job fails:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

It seems that the git clone of the repo is being executed with Jenkins user and not with user that have right access in this node, so, is there any way to specify in Jenkinsfile which public key file must be used by the job? This is current Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    node {
        label 'node-example'
        customWorkspace '/Users/node-example/dev'
    }
  }
  stages {
      stage('Example') {
          steps {
              sh './example.sh'
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to that was change username in Jenkins credetial to 'git'. It solves the issue.